# Webmethods with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, webmethods

I'm a new to WebMethods. I'm interested in learning Webmethods by starting a self study and move on to other modes later. To jumpstart I need a pointer which can answer "What is Webmethods?" "Where is it useful?" and "What is it composed off?" . I have experience in PHP development. I also tried to google it, but www.wmusers.com is what I saw next to wikipedia. If some one could guide me in learning Webmethods, I really appreciate that.

Comment: I think you're actually looking for web services. Am I right ?

Comment: This is a forum type question and SO is not a forum.

Comment: Yes Web Services thats what I need to know. From where exactly to start.

Comment: http://www.wmusers.com is migrated to http://techcommunity.softwareag.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the documentation from Software AG at http://documentation.softwareag.com/.

Apart from that I think the easiest way to learn is to start working with it.